# What "symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpylontesting.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5Pylon15PylonInitializeEv" means?

Tags: java, c++, linux, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I am trying to use some c++'s libraries in Java (IDE is NetBeans). I have created the shared library, which is called "pylontesting.so". The following code is what it was used to create it:

> g++ -fPIC -lbxapi -lbxapi-6.3.0 -lGCBase_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon -lGenApi_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon -lgxapi -lgxapi-6.3.0 -llog4cpp_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon -lLog_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon -lMathParser_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon -lNodeMapData_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon -lpylonbase -lpylonbase-6.3.0 -lpylonc -lpylonc-6.3.0 -lpylon_TL_bcon -lpylon_TL_bcon-6.3.0 -lpylon_TL_camemu -lpylon_TL_camemu-6.3.0 -lpylon_TL_gige -lpylon_TL_gige-6.3.0 -lpylon_TL_gtc -lpylon_TL_gtc-6.3.0 -lpylon_TL_usb -lpylon_TL_usb-6.3.0 -lpylonutility -lpylonutility-6.3.0 -luxapi -luxapi-6.3.0 -lXmlParser_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon  -L/opt/pylon/lib -I/opt/pylon/include -I/home/fra/NetBeansProjects/TestPylon/src/main/java/Pylon -I/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include -I/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -shared -o libpylontesting.so Pylon_NativeTest.cpp

This might look a mess, but basically I'm linking every libraries I need through the command "-l" and tell the linker where the libraries are using "-L" and then using "-I" for the headers into the c++ code. The c++ code that I'm using is the following:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Pylon_NativeTest.h"
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
#    include <pylon/PylonGUI.h>
#endif

using namespace Pylon;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Pylon_NativeTest_Initialize (JNIEnv *, jobject){

  PylonInitialize();
  
  }
```

Its purpose is to export this simple library function called "PylonInitialize()". Then, I also have created my java file:

```
package Pylon;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class NativeTest {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("pylontesting");
    }
   private native void Initialize();
   
   public static void main(String args[]){
       new NativeTest().Initialize();
   }
    
}
```

Which should call the function "PylonInitialize()" from the shared library created and called "pylontesting". But when I run the java main, it throws me the error:

> usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpylontesting.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5Pylon15PylonInitializeEv
> Command execution failed.
> I'm using Maven as a compiler, and working under Ubuntu 21.10. Any ideas?